# Assigning value to an array item, Game of life

Tags: c#

Im new to c# and trying to code Conways Game of Life, but I have this problem. I have a class Gameboard:

```
 public class GameBoard
{
    int height = 32;
    int width = 32;

    public void Create()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
            {
                Tile[,] tile = new Tile[1024, 2];
                tile[x, y]= tile[,].value;   // not working

                Console.Write( "");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

and Tile class:

```
  public class Tile
{
    public int value = 0;
}
```

I want to be able to assign a value to every tile in Create method and I need that value to be from Tile class, I also have some methods changing the value in Tile class so I need a reference to it. My plan is to set all the values of tile[x,y] to zeros and then change accordingly to the rules to ones. How do I assign the Tile value propertz to tile[x,y] array item?

Comment: Hint: your array should be a field, and should be initialized *outside* the loop. I'd also expect your array to be of size `[width, height]`, not `[1024, 2]`. Also, if your tile values are really just on/off, consider using a `bool[,]` instead... I don't think your `Tile` class is really adding any value here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to note:

1. The way it is now, the `Tile` array is initialized (setting `= new Tile[1024, 2];`) every time you iterate through the inner loop. This will remove any value you've stored in it. Your `Tile` array should probably be a field of Gameboard since you'll most likely want to access this outside of the class. What this means is that you'll need to move the declaration of your `Tile` array to underneath the height and width values.
2. You'll also want to check the size that you're setting the array to. It seems that your board should be the dimensions set by height and width. So when you initialize the array, you'd want to use width and height.
3. Another change you might consider is creating a constructor and initializing everything there. A constructor acts similarly to a method in the sense that you have parameters and can execute code within the body. For the most part, the parameters are just used to initialize the fields within the class. In your case, this would allow you to easily create GameBoards of different sizes.
4. I'm a little confused as to why you are writing lines in your foreach. Debugging?
5. The iterators on your for-loops (x and y) should start at 0. If you declare an array of size 32 then it will have indexes from 0 to 31. So if your array was named tiles and was initialized `Tile[] tiles = new Tile[32];` You could access values `tiles[0]` to `tiles[31]`.

Here are the changes I mentioned above.

```
    public class GameBoard
    {
        private int _height;
        private int _width;
        public Tile[,] Tiles; // Tile array is now a field

        public GameBoard(int height, int width)
        {
           _height = height;
           _width = width;
           Tiles = new Tile[width, height]; 
        }

    // I'm fairly certain the default value for c# of an integer is 0
    // so you may not need the following.

        public void SetGameBoardValues()
        {
            Random rand = new Random(); //only add if you want to randomly generate the board

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)//arrays start at 0
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)//arrays start at 0
               {
                   Tiles[x, y] = 0;
                   // If you'd like to randomly assign the value you can do:
                   Tile[x,y] = rand.Next(0,2)
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can now access this from a different class through this manner:

```
public class Main
{
   public static int main(string [] args) //if you're using the console
   {
      GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(32, 32); // gameboard is size 32x32
      gameBoard.SetGameBoardValues();

      gameBoard.Tiles[0, 0] = 1; //You can access values this way.
   }
}
```